# remove value from array what the words is not fully match

Tags: php, arrays

How i can remove a value from array what is not fully match the letters.

Array code example:

```
$Array = array(
 'Funny',
 'funnY',
 'Games',
);
```

How I can unset all values from this array what is 'funny'

I try via unset('funny'); but is not removing the values from array, is removed just if i have 'funny' on array but 'funnY' or 'Funny' not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is some sophisticated solution with `array_intersect_key` or something which could do this in one line but I assume this approach is more easily read:

```
function removeCaseInsensitive($array, $toRemove) {
    $ret = [];
    foreach ($array as $v) {
        if (strtolower($v) != strtolower($toRemove))
            $ret[] = $v;
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

This returns a new array that does not contain any case of `$toRemove`. If you want to keep the keys than you can do this:

```
function removeCaseInsensitive($array, $toRemove) {
    $keep = [];
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        if (strtolower($v) != strtolower($toRemove))
            $keep[$k] = true;
    }
    return array_intersect_keys($array, $keep);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can filter out those values with a loose filtering rule:

```
$array = array_filter($array, function($value) {
    return strtolower($value) !== 'funny';
});
```

Comment: Show what the output is from your example code this is how you make your answers fit OP's question